# Convert or cast varchar rows like (Mon Jul 18 19:28:36 EDT 2018) To DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a column varchar type with dates like:

```
Fri Mar 3 12:55:17 EST 2017
Thu Jul 27 10:12:07 EDT 2017
Fri Jul 21 12:11:35 EDT 2017
Wed Jan 31 13:15:34 EST 2018
```

And I would like to return just the date and time something like:

```
03/03/2017 12:55:17
07/27/2017 10:12:07
07/21/2017 12:11:35
01/31/2018 13:15:34
```

I tried several ways with substring and convert statement but nothing work.

Any assistance in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Fri Mar 3 12:55:17 EST 2017'),
('Thu Jul 27 10:12:07 EDT 2017'),
('Fri Jul 21 12:11:35 EDT 2017'),
('Wed Jan 31 13:15:34 EST 2018')

Select *
      ,AsDateTime = try_convert(datetime,substring(SomeCol,4,len(SomeCol)-11)+right(SomeCol,4))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol                         AsDateTime
Fri Mar 3 12:55:17 EST 2017     2017-03-03 12:55:17.000
Thu Jul 27 10:12:07 EDT 2017    2017-07-27 10:12:07.000
Fri Jul 21 12:11:35 EDT 2017    2017-07-21 12:11:35.000
Wed Jan 31 13:15:34 EST 2018    2018-01-31 13:15:34.000
```

Comment: Nice! Is working, it is any possibility to return that without .000 ?

Comment: @JCACERES Happy to help.  The .000 part of the datetime datatype.  If you want it as a string, you can wrap the expression in format() For example:  format(try_convert(datetime,substring(SomeCol,4,len(SomeCol)-11)+right(SomeCol,4)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

Comment: Excellent !!, Thank you very much.